# Automator workflow hangs when run as folder action

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, automator

I've got an Automator workflow that is supposed to backup the contents of my USB stick whenever I plug it in (after asking for a confirmation). It works if I trigger it manually within the Automator GUI. When I save it as a folder action, the workflow is triggered as expected (I get the confirmation prompt) but then gets stuck somewhere.

What options do I have to find out what is going wrong? In what does the environment of the workflow differ when it's called as a folder action?

[image: annotated workflow]

Comment: Does it work when not run as folder action, but e.g. started as a Service?

Comment: @DanielBeck How would I do this?

Comment: @slhck see linked file

Comment: Use *File »  Duplicate To…* in Automator, then select *Service*. It'll then show up in the *Services* sub-menu of the application menu (the menu whose label is the active application's name). Click to launch.

Comment: Consider uploading the workflow as a screenshot image to imgur via this site's upload functionality, and annotating it within your question. There's no lasting value in linking a file automatically deleted within a month.

Comment: @DanielBeck I don't have a "Duplicate To" item in my file menu. I've tried to create a new service, but I can't seem to import the actions from the folder action.

Comment: Are you using a version of OS X that has been superseded by a major release? If so, that information would *really* be helpful. On Lion's Automator, the menu item exists. If you don't have it, just create a new "document" in Automator, select *Service* as its type, and recreate the steps in your current Automator document.

Comment: @DanielBeck You're right, I've added the image to the post. I'm using 10.6.8 because I've got some software that does not yet fully support Lion.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've recreated the workflow as a service and it works. Don't know whether that's good or bad...

Comment: Could this be a timing issue? Have you tried waiting a few seconds, or duplicating the first volume check step for the USB stick? Maybe `Volumes` changes before it's actually mounted..?

Comment: @DanielBeck That seems to have done the trick. Would you like to answer for yourself so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is only checking whether the encrypted volume exists, not the USB stick.

Make sure the folder action isn't triggered because of something else by adding a check for the destination volume to the workflow.

In general, if something's not working when automatically triggered, it's best to replicate as much as possible in a manually started process. In that case, executing within Automator or making it a service or application instead proved to be useful for finding the issue.